# Как загрузить файл в SoundPool по URI?

Tags: java, android, аудио, uri

Как загрузить звук в soundpool из URI? Сейчас таким методом не работает. Хотя из raw все грузит.

```
// используем класс SoundPool.Builder, если используется Android 5.0 и выше
        // иначе вызываем конструктор
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .build();

            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(6)
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                    .build();
        } else {
            soundPool = new SoundPool(6, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        }

        // находим элементы
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        ib1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib1);
        ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib2);
        ib3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib3);
        ib4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib4);
        ib5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib5);
        ib6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib6);
        btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        sRepeat = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.sRepeat);

        // устанавливаем слушатели
        ib1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib2.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib3.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib4.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib5.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib6.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);

        // получаем uri адреса
        Uri i1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.zaitseva.lab2/" + R.raw.s1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i1 + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Uri i2 = Uri.parse("file:///Ringtones/z.mp3");
        Uri i3 = Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI;

        // указываем адреса звуков
        sound1 = soundPool.load(i1.getPath(), 1);
        sound2 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.s2, 1);
        sound3 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.s3, 1);
        sound4 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.s4, 1);
        sound5 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.s5, 1);
        sound6 = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.s6, 1);
```

Comment: А Вы уверены, что `SoundPool` Вам вообще подходит - у него ведь ограничение в несколько секунд. И о каком конкретно `URI` идёт речь: файл, сеть, ресурс свой, чужой, контент провайдера?

Comment: Да - нужно SoundPool, по заданию лабораторной. В принципе вообще никакой URI не получается, ни файл, ни сеть, ни свой ресурс. Нужно хоть какой-нибудь пример

Comment: Подзабыл я уже этот класс... Думаю он вообще не поддерживает `uri`, только ресурсы и файлы. То есть параметр `path` должен содержать реальный путь к файлу типа: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES) + "/z.mp3"`. Соответственно у приложения должен быть доступ к этому файлу.